# How to delete "auto-added span" inside <button>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have that `<a> (Edit diagram + icons)` inside `<ul><li>...</ul></li>`

[image]

I want to add click*able* and hover*able* arrow icon inside that `<a>`

[image]

So i created button with **display: contents**, *some code*:

```
...
<li class="active">
   <a href="#"><span class="fa fas fa-edit mr-3"></span> Edit diagram
      <button onclick="location.href='/drawdiagram'" class="fas fa-reply mr-3" style="display: contents"> 
      </button>
   </a>
</li>
...
```

And here is my problem. Look at that screen:
[image]

Inside my button tag, `<span>` was added... This span is adding some css, i mean some paddding etc. And the result is on that picture -.-
That green rectangle anoying me. For first it is adding margin from bottom to my `<li>`. **For second and worst, it is adding extra area where i can move my mouse and my arrow will be hovered.**
[image]

My mouse can be there and the arrow will be hovered all time -.-

That extra `<span>` is added by jQuery but I don't want to rummage inside library.

**So the question is, anyone have idea what i can do it with this?** I had an idea to delete "somehow" that span using JavaScript or jQuery but i have no idea how to do it. Or maybe i can "somehow" delete it using css. But remember, I don't want to rummage inside library.

Comment: What is causing it to be added in the first place?

Comment: You mean what is causing (`<span>`) to be added in the first place?

Comment: Yes ..............

Comment: That lines of jQuery ui

https://imgur.com/lD9JFNB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are many ways to do that.
but very first you have to confirm if you remove this `<span>` which is inside button, yours icon will not disturbed. for test just remove it with the help of inspect element(hope you knows. how to do it).
if its fine with removing this `<span>` then with the help of JQuery you can remove it via adding this line.
`$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#ID_of_button span').remove(); 
}`

Comment: Thanks man, i deleted this using your way and now everything is ok :D